# Deleted certificates keep returning in Key Chain

Tags: ios, keychain

I have deleted all developer and distribution `certificates` from the Developer site and from my `Key Chain` but some cerificates still keep returning into my `Key Chain`. Why might that be?

Comment: Is Xcode downloading them for you?

Comment: Yes - when I Refresh from Developer Portal in Organiser but they are deleted on the developer side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by keys, associated with those certs, that are still in your keychain.

**If Using Xcode 4...**

Xcode 4 was supposed to allow one to manage their signing certs, but it was always wonky for me. Here is how I handled this issue last May.

Go to Keychain Access -> My Certificates and search for "iPhone". Your Developer and Distribution certs will show-up, old and current. Expand the certs that you **don't want** and you'll see the keys associated with those certs. Deleting the keys associated with the certs you want to delete is....well, key.

I *think* you can delete the keys in "My Certificates". If not, just go to "Keys", find and delete those rogue keys.

If none of your signing certificates are valid after this, then you will have to regenerate the signing certificates. [Creating Your Signing Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW1) will show you how to do that.

**If Using Xcode 5...**

Xcode 5 is, according to Apple, the way to manage certificates. You can of course still do this manually, as detailed in [Creating Your Signing Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW1). But in Xcode 5, Preferences, Account, signing-in to your dev account and then View Details... will take you to an area where you can manage your signing certs.

If someone has a better way of handling this, please chime-in.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have deleted the keys but now no certificates appear valid. How do I add the keys again?

Comment: That didn't happen to me. No sweat. First, quit Keychain Access. Next, go to Xcode–btw, which version of Xcode are you using?–in any case, in Xcode, refresh your provisioning profiles. Now reopen Keychain Access. If the iOS Dev and Dist Certs are still invalid, then you'll need to recreate them, which will also recreate the keys. Here's the link that discusses how to generate your Dev or Distribution signing certs, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW1.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I discovered with the keychain when removing a certificate is that if I remove it from the certificate section the certificate is not "really" removed, but if choose "all elements" and from there I delete the certificate then it works... maybe it does not work for you but you can try