# Deleted iOS Certificate keeps showing up in keychain when restarting Xcode even after deleting it from keychain access and App Store Connect

Tags: ios, keychain, xcode11, code-signing-certificate

I recently came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802971/deleted-certificates-keep-returning-in-key-chain) which seems identical to my issue but I wasn't able to achieve my desired result from it.

I am using Fastlane + match on a react native application to upload my build to TestFlight. To let match handle code signing, I need to delete older provisioning profiles and certificates.  I have been able to delete the provisioning profiles and all certificates except for **one** certificate. I revoked my certificates from the app store connect and deleted them inside my `keychain`. However, whenever I restart Xcode (version 11.5), my deleted certificate comes back and is found inside app store connect and `keychain`.

I also deleted Xcode's derived data because I thought maybe that is where this information was being cached, but even then, the certificate keeps coming back.

Any idea how I can permanently delete this certificate and have it not come back when I start up Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the revoked certificate from keychain then quit keychain if logged in  Xcode remove that developer account from Xcode preference then quit Xcode then launch it again then   Try once logging with the same developer account to your Xcode  download all required certificates and check whether its working or not

Comment: So it seems the original certificate keeps coming back because it isn't allowed to be deleted from the apple developer site. That certificate was the first certificate assigned via apple to the account owner. Once I looked into the certificate on the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list) I saw it didn't have an option to delete, unlike the other certificates.